# How to set value to Interface XML file in C#

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

I have a list of people.

```js
List<People> people = new List<People>
  {
    new People() {Id = 1, FirstName = "Will", LastName = "Petit", Address = "123 Street", Type = "Student" },
    new People() {Id = 2, FirstName = "Anna", LastName = "Poter", Address = "123 Street", Type = "Employee"}
  }
```

So, I just researched XML and I want to set value to XML and check my XML schema from People's list. How can I do that ? Please help me.

Final result is:

```
<x:People xmlns:x="http://www.w3schools.com">
  <Student NoId="1">
    <FirstName>Will</FirstName>
    <LastName>Petit</LastName>
    <Address>123 Street</Address>
  </Student>
  <Employee NoId="2">
    <FirstName>Anna</FirstName>
    <LastName>Poter</LastName>
    <Address>123 Street</Address>
  </Employee>
</x:People>
```

Comment: How these two xmls are related? Your question is quite unclear. Probably you should add some more details - what are you trying to do and what have you tried so far.

Comment: I have a list of people and I want to export them to XML. Can I use XmlSerializer to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Your first sample file is a [schema](http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema) document (sometimes has the extension `xsd` when on disk) - it defines the form of an XML document.

Your second sample file is an XML file - this can be validated against the schema to check that it conforms with the specified content.

There are varied tools that exist that will generate an empty or default document from the XSD (XML Spy for instance) or you can use Visual Studio to do it ([here is an example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd489258%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from MSDN). You can also do it with code [like this MSDN example.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx)

But you will need to set the values yourself from whatever source you have. Your question is too vague to provide a code sample for setting the values as you haven't provided any information on where they come from.

Edit: Incidentally, the sample XML you provide is NOT valid - the `Student` and `Employee` elements are missing the mandatory `Address` element, and the namespace isn't in the schema either. Here is a valid XML document according to the schema:

```
<People>
    <Student NoId="1">
        <FirstName>Will</FirstName>
        <LastName>Petit</LastName>
        <Address>1 Test Street</Address>
    </Student>
    <Employee NoId="2">
        <FirstName>Anna</FirstName>
        <LastName>Poter</LastName>
        <Address>Flat 2, Stack Overflow Apartments</Address>
    </Employee>
</People>
```